# Sample size when looking for a rare attribute

Tags: sample-size

BASED ON THE EXCHANGE OF COMMENTS OF BELOW, I KNOW REALIZE THIS THE WRONG QUESTION

I know similar questions have been asked, but I haven’t been able to find a satisfactory answer.

I have a population of about 5M for which I want to estimate how many have a particular attribute, which is either true or false.  To do this, I would like to use a sample, but I'm having difficulty determining the right sample size.

I've been looking at Cochran's Sample Size Formula

z^2 * p * q / e^2

where 
z is the z-value
p is the estimated proportion of the operation which has the attribute
q is 1 - p
e is the margin of error

using a Z value of 1.96 and a p value of .5 I get

(1.96^2 * 0.5 * 0.5) / 0.05^2

or a sample size of 384.

My challenge is that, I believe my attribute is fairly rare--less than a half percent of the population.  As such, it seems likely that my random sample would contain 0 samples that have the attribute.  I can change P to reflect the hypothesis distribution, but that further lowers the sample size.

What is the right way to think about the sample size, when looking for a rare attribute.

Comment: Isn't 5% a pretty wide margin on a value you expect to be 0.5%?

Comment: Perhaps that is where my misunderstanding is.  Is the margin of error on the total population as opposed to the observed number with the attribute?  In other words, does a 5% margin of error mean 5% on the 5M (which would be 250K) and not 5% on whatever the observed number is with the population?

Comment: 5% on the observed number but on the full scale, not 5% of the observed value. The approximation fails in the tails but let's pretend it doesn't, you're basically asking for a sample size that would let you estimate the rate is <5%. If you already expect the rate is 0.5% with some confidence, then a study that shows you it's less than 5% isn't really giving you new information.

Comment: Very helpful thank you Bryan!